# regex match to detect url pathname

Tags: regex, typescript

I want to detect if given string is a pathname or not in typescript

For example, the followings are valid pathnames

```
/
/abc
/abc/def
/abc/def/
/abc/def/ghj
```

But these are not valid

```
///
/abc//
abc
abc/
```

So far, I have `^\/\w+` but it doesnt work for all cases.
How can I improve it?

Comment: perhaps you can avoid using regex by using URL constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
^\/(\w+\/)*\w*$
```

which attempts to match:

- `\/`: a slash
- `(\w+\/)*`: multiple combinations of alphanumerical characters + slash (even zero)
- `\w*`: an optional combination of alphanumerical characters

between start of string `^` and end of string `$`.

Check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/1mXLHp/1).